# How do I force the url bar to show for iOS and stay on? Once my website loads the URL disappears

Tags: iphone

How do I force the url bar to show for iOS and stay on? Once my website loads the URL disappears.

I know that if the user taps on the time the URL shows but most of my users do not know that.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behavior on iOS and mobile Safari and thus is it not meant to be changed. The view is being scrolled down after the page loads to hide the navigation bar.

Comment: What I am looking for is what amazon.com and apple.com are doing. When you go to their pages the url bar does not go away.

Comment: It only doesn't hide when the page is small enough for everything to fit on screen. amazon.com hides on iOS 6.1.3

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to answer. I have to ask, Amazon and Boston.com have extra content and the page still shows the url.